# Подгрузка данных jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

есть таблица html в которую подгружаются элементы `<tr>` с контентом

```
<table width="100%" id="load_msg_cont">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="message getmsg"><span>Hi</span></div>
                            <input type="hidden" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="message sentmsg"><span>Hello</span></div>
                            <input type="hidden" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </table>
```

Есть страница load_msg с которой подгружаются элементы, на ней один или несколько элементов по типу:

```
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="message sentmsg"><span>Hello</span></div>
                            <input type="hidden" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

Написал строку подгрузки  `$('#load_msg_cont').append($('<tr>').load('load_msg'));`
Подскажите, как сделать все то же самое, не дублируя `<tr>`

Comment: .......непонятно....

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, что непонятного? <tr> дублируется из-за того, что я делаю append через <tr>, помещая в него элементы со страницы load_msg, помещенные в те же <tr> теги.  Мне нужно добавить tr теги в таблицу, не затрагивая ранее загруженные.

Comment: ну так делай append() только для тех данных, которые нужны.

Comment: @Jean-Claude в том и прикол, что мне не нужно никакие данные апендить. Мне надо просто подгрузить содержимое load_msg, добавить подгруженные элементы <tr> в таблицу

Comment: ну тогда делай load в таблицу ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @АлексейШиманский если делаю load в таблицу, все что было в ней ранее пропадает, и остаются только те данные которые я только что подгрузил. Мне надо выполнить подгрузку с сохранением предыдущих элементов

Comment: значит тебе нужен append 

Comment: ну так делай апенд вновь созданных строк с подгруженными данными ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: апенд вновь созданных строк... а если у меня там 10к сообщений?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделай вместо load другой метод подгрузки данных, например так:

```
$.get("ajax/test.html", function (data) { 
    $("#load_msg_cont").append(data);
});
```

Тогда данные спокойно можно *добавить* через `append` к уже имеющимся.

Comment: о, благодарю, то что нужно